# Could ByteBuffer implement DataOutput/DataInput?

Tags: java, serialization, nio, bytebuffer

Is there some subtle reason why [java.nio.ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) does not implement [java.io.DataOutput](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html) or [java.io.DataInput](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html), or did the authors just not choose to do this?  It would seem straightforward to map the calls (e.g. putInt() -> writeInt()).

The basic problem I (and some [others](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5349181), apparently) have is older classes which know how to serialize/serialize themselves using the generic interfaces: DataInput/DataOutput.  I would like to reuse my custom serialization without writing a custom proxy for ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap the buffer in [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) or [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) using the `put()` or `wrap()` methods.  The problem with having a `ByteBuffer` directly emulate a datainput/output stream has to do with not knowing the sizes in advance.  What if there's an overrun?

What is needed is a `ByteBufferOutputStream` in which you can wrap / expose the required behaviors.  Examples of this exist; the [Apache avro](http://avro.apache.org/) serialization scheme has such a thing.  It's not too hard to roll your own.  Why is there not one by default?  Well, it's not a perfect world...

```
ByteArrayOutputStream backing = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutput foo = new DataOutputStream(backing); 
// do your serialization out to foo

foo.close();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(backing.toByteArray());
// now you've got a bytebuffer...
```

Comment: + for mentioning Avero, it looks interesting.

Comment: Overrun on read should throw EOFException; overrun on write would be treated just like writing to a full volume (or just throw EOF as well)

Comment: @Justin: Looking at the `DataOutput` api, yeah, that might work fine.  Maybe it's worth a little experiment to make sure you can proxy `DataOutput` down onto a `ByteBuffer` cleanly and posting a bug at the oracle site or contacting the nio expert group.  It may be that these two apis are intended to target different levels of abstraction; I'm not sure.

Comment: @Justin: This also might be interesting to you.  http://mina.apache.org/iobuffer.html

Comment: For the `InputStream` case, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332264/wrapping-a-bytebuffer-with-an-inputstream

Comment: Why are you calling close() on foo when it has no such method?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutput.html

Answer (score 4):

A better way that works with direct buffers too:

```
class ByteBufferOutputStream extends OutputStream
{
    private final ByteBuffer buffer;

    public ByteBufferOutputStream(ByteBuffer buffer)
    {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException
    {
        buffer.put((byte) b);
    }
}
```

Note that this requires calling buffer.flip() after you are done writing to it, before you can read from it.