# Using a ByteBuffer with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, bytebuffer

I am using a messaging service that returns me a `ByteBuffer` which contains some XML that I want to use JAXB to deserialize.

Is there a direct way (using JAXBs Unmarshaller) to deserialize the ByteBuffer or is converting this to a string and then deserializing that the only way?

Comment: You may find the following useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332264/wrapping-a-bytebuffer-with-an-inputstream

Answer (score 2):

It should be fairly trivial to wrap a ByteBuffer in an InputStream which JAXB should be able to accept as input:

```
public class ByteBufferInputStream extends InputStream {
    private ByteBuffer byteBuffer;

    public ByteBufferInputStream(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
        this.byteBuffer = byteBuffer;
    }


    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if(byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
            return byteBuffer.get();
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```