# Iterating over a Bytebuffer of chars in java

Tags: java, iteration, bytebuffer

Im having issue finding a solution to this problem.
I have a Bytebuffer of chars(lines of text to be exact) and I need to find a sub-string in that buffer.
The easiest solution would be to convert that ByteBuffer to a string and then work with that string however that solution requires me to double(at least) the amount of memory I use in the stack(or heap) of my program and I dont want that, I would rather do something along the lines of each line convert it to string and then work with that. Is there and easy way doing that?
thanks.

Comment: Try creating an [InputStream from the ByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332264/wrapping-a-bytebuffer-with-an-inputstream), then using a BufferedReader.

Comment: Thanks for the comment im trying to experiment with ByteArrayInputStream hopefully that will do the trick.

Comment: `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteBufferInputStream` are NOT the same thing.   (Just saying .....)

Answer (score 1):

You could read from the `ByteBuffer` some bytes in a buffer until finding a breakline character or a character that doesn't make part of the `String` to find.
You could use this method :

```
java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(byte[] dst, int offset, int length)
```

Then convert the bytes into a `String` `(new String(bytes, yourEncoding))` and check if it contains the `String` to match.
Otherwise read the following bytes and repeat the same processing.

Comment: Isn't it weird that `ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer()` doesn't allow you to specify the encoding?

Comment: It is true. We could also use the instance method of Charset `charset.decode(byteBuffer)` but it will consume more memory

Comment: Yes, but if `ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer()` allowed to specify an encoding, it could be used efficiently as it doesn't copy the buffer, only creates a view of it.

Comment: I agree with Kayman that is why im having issues working with ByteBuffer only and need to convert is to another class..